# With CMD wrong output subprocess with ffmpeg/ffprobe

Tags: python, audio, cmd, ffmpeg, ffprobe

i have a problem with ffmpeg when i run it in the cmd i havethe correct output `"ffprobe passionfruit.mp4 -show_streams"`

But when i use the same with subprocess :

```
command = 'ffprobe "C:/Users/NMASLORZ/Downloads/passionfruit.mp4" -show_streams'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
text = p.stdout.read()
retcode = p.wait()
print (text)
```

i have this output :
"'ffprobe' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file."
i tried every synthax and even in a list i still have the same output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your Windows terminal reads system's PATH or has otherwise defined path to the `ffprobe`. When you run `Popen` with `shell=True` it runs the execution through shell that might or might not (your case) have access to that PATH.

Possible solutions:

1. Provide full path to `ffprobe` (easiest):

```
command = 'C:\whatever\ffprobe.exe "C:/Users/NMASLORZ/Downloads/passionfruit.mp4" -show_streams'
```

2. Use `shell=False`. Might not work, depends on your system.

```
command = ('ffprobe', 'C:/Users/NMASLORZ/Downloads/passionfruit.mp4', '-show_streams')
p = subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

3. Add `PATH` through `env` variable and in that PATH add `ffprobe`.

> If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment. It is passed directly to Popen.

Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for further guidance.

Comment: @NicolasMaslorz This is a really high quality answer, helped me as well.